# Index Match, except if

Tags: excel, indexing

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX('Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293,MATCH(1,IF('Other sheet'!$A$3:$A$5293=$A3,IF('Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293=MAX(IF('Other sheet'!$A$3:$A$5293=$A3,'Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293)),1)),0))," --- ? ---")}
```

Hi there, just wondering if anyone has anything to help with this purpose - for a given array found that does match `A3`, if any of the of the values in the `O` column are equal to the word "Undefined" than the resulting value should be read as "Undefined".

Currently column `O` is a list of a dates and the formula should be bring back the most recent, unless one of the values in the date column `O` is "Undefined", in which case value for the formula should be "Undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Using `INDEX/MATCH` isn't usually the best approach for this type of calculation, you can get the same result with this formula:

`=IFERROR(LARGE(IF('Other sheet'!$A$3:$A$5293=$A3,'Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293),1)," --- ? ---")`

Confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Now to add your extra condition use `COUNTIFS` function

`=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS('Other sheet'!$A$3:$A$5293,$A3,'Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293,"Undefined")>0,"Undefined",LARGE(IF('Other sheet'!$A$3:$A$5293=$A3,'Other sheet'!$O$3:$O$5293),1))," --- ? ---")`

I used `LARGE` instead of `MAX` here because `MAX` gives zero if there are no values to evaluate, `LARGE` will give an error in that situation, which works better in this context